# Adding 1 to a number in C

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, integer-arithmetic

I have to add 1 to a number in C. I have to do this without arithmetic operators like '+', '++', .. so on.

I have written following line of code.

```
int a = 1234;
int b = 1;
printf("%d", a ^ b);
```

This works fine till the integer limit is reached i.e., for 32 bit it is 4294967295. But I see in many other websites that to perform the same they do AND of two numbers, followed by XOR and left shift.

Please suggest whether my approach is correct as I am novice in C.

Comment: Umm... what about `+`

Comment: Bitwise XOR doesn't *add* one to a number, it *toggles* bits, in your case the least significant bit.

Comment: When `a` is `1235` the result is `1234`. Is this what you intended? Because this is not "adding 1 to a number".

Comment: The `^` operator is a half-adder: it adds one, and ignores the carry.

Comment: As @dasblinkenlight said, you performed a half-add operation, which doesn't take carries into account. What you want is a full adder.

Comment: Seriously?! It's very simple-Use "a++" to increment "a" by 1

Comment: but I have to do this without arithmetic operators like '+', '++',.. so on

Comment: puneet, if you have a more specific task than "add one to a number", please specify *all* your constraints exactly. For example, when you say "'+', '++',... so on" that is not precise enough. Please specify exactly what you can and cannot use. Otherwise, we cannot know how to help you. For the question that you have asked, using `+` is the only sensible answer.

Comment: Doing something like this seems trivial at first, but it actually isn't. Consider what happens when you perform 9999+1. For each 9 digit, you must also account for the carried digit. This process is referred to in circuit design as a ripple-carry algorithm, where you compute each sum using a full adder, accounting for the carry. You can [read more on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_%28electronics%29). There are other adder designs listed there of course, so take your pick. Just remember some are more difficult than others to implement. I mentioned ripple-carry since it's easy.

Comment: @jww How else do you reliably add two numbers without the `+` operator?

Comment: @Chrono - I saw his comment about no arithmetic operations after I commented to you. Sorry about that. I added that to his question and then moved to re-open. His question and your comment make more sense now.

Answer (score 5):

Your approach is not correct. You should use `+` to add numbers in C:

```
int a = 1234;
int b = 1;
printf("%d\n", a + b); // Prints 1235
```

You say "This works fine till the integer limit is reached" about your approach, but you are mistaken. When `a` is an odd number, the result of the `^` operation is a subtraction of one:

```
int a = 1235;
int b = 1;
printf("%d\n", a ^ b); // Prints 1234
printf("%d\n", a + b); // Prints 1236, using the correct operator
```

Here you can see that the approach you are currently using is not correct for odd numbers.

Answer (score 2):

In this method you are not doing exact addition. but it looks like.

```
   a = 00000000 00000000 00000100 11010010
   b = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
 ------------------------------------------
 a^b = 00000000 00000000 00000100 11010011
 ------------------------------------------
                                         ^ this bit is toggled
```

For example when you try to XOR 3 with 1234, you will get output as 1233. because of XOR operation

```
   a = 00000000 00000000 00000100 11010010
   b = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000011
 ------------------------------------------
 a^b = 00000000 00000000 00000100 11010001
 ------------------------------------------
                                        ^ here this bit is toggled.
```

When you use XOR for addition it is not meaning that you are adding. So keep this in mind and do the necessary operations!

Comment: *"Always prefer+ for addition..."* - OP added an important comment after you posted your answer. He cannot use arithmetic operations. I suppose that means he is only allowed to use bitwise operations.

Answer (score 0):

`^` is used to do a XOR operation, and `+` is used to do an "add" operation.
I highly recommed `+` to perform any kind of adding stuff, like the sum of two numbers, or the subtraction of a number and the negative of another number, or incrementing the value of a variable in some amount.

Besides, it is possile to increment in exactly "1" the value a variable by using the `++` unary operators: `x++` is equivalent to `x = x + 1`.

Also, the `+=` operator is available, which increments the variable by the quantity specified at the right: `x += 1`.

If one is lucky, it is possible to choose an arbitrary operator, say `<OPER>`, and write some expression, like `x <OPER> <FREAK OPERAND>` and thus to obtain the effect of "adding 1" to the variable.
But then it could be difficult to generalize this approach to more complicated situations (for exammple, the **"add 2"** operation).